# use of PHPMailer about some of its methods e.g. `addReplyTo()` & `setFrom()`

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
$mail->Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "h*****@outlook.com";
$mail->Password = "********";
$mail->setFrom("h****@gmail.com", "Z***** Hao");
$mail->addReplyTo("a********@yahoo.com", "Z****** Hao");
$mail->addAddress("h******@qq.com", "Z**** Hao");
```

Above is my code try to use PHPMailer sending email through the outlook smtp server,and my qq mailbox received an email from my outlook account,but I thought it would be sent from my gmail account since I used the `setFrom()` method,and also how can the `$mail->addReplyTo` statement play a part in it?

And as a beginner I write it down by referencing an example on github page of PHPMailer project,it's the [Link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps).

Comment: Why don't you base your code on the example you pointed to instead of making up settings that won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As currently configured, you're doing this:

- `Host`, `Port`, `SMTPSecure`, `SMTPAuth`: Configure the mail server you want to use to send out the e-mail. In this case it's the Outlook SMTP server.
- `Username` and `Password`: Credentials you're using to login to the Outlook SMTP server.
- `setFrom` sets the From header in the email message. You're currently setting this to your Gmail address, so most of the time, the receiving party sees this address in his/her email client in the from field. But: this header isn't always respected by the sending SMTP server. It could be replaced by the email address belonging to your credentials to prevent spam.
- `addReplyTo` allows you to set a different reply-to address. If not set, the client will suggest to sent an email to the address as specified in the From field. This allows you to overwrite it.